# Transformation Sprite with finger move

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am making an Drawing App in someway like Paint in Windows
I have a toolbar with many shapes button such as Rectangle, Circle, Triangle, etc. When tap a button i add a sprite with shape with button's name.

I want to add functions like this
- When tap on shape it show four 4 points each corner of shape that i can touch and drag to skew or scale.
Same as we do with an image in photoshop or MSWord
anyone have sample code or tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for your app.

[Paint](http://code4app.net/ios/Paint-Pad/4fcf74876803faec66000000)

[Drawing](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/acedrawingview)

[Drawing2](http://code4app.com/down/id/509771406803faca4f000000)

Comment: tks for that demo code. But it's not what i want. When i tap a button on menu, i'll create a sprite class with image file. Then tap that image it will appear 4 points at 4 corners and i can tap a point to distort the image, like in photoshop.

Comment: tks so much, last thing is can do this in cocos2d or kobold2d